# How do I send and receive vars with jquery and AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get

so lets say this is my jquery portion of the code:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: false
});

load() functions
var loadUrl = "load.php";
$("#load_basic").click(function(){
    $("#result").load(loadUrl +  "?language=php&version=5");
});

});
```

and this is "load.php"

```
<?php $_GET['language'] .= "cool";  $_GET['version']+=2; ?>
```

How do I return the processed language and version vars back to my #result div?

Sorry if I'm doing this wrong. Pretty comfortable in php and jquery, but ajax sort of confuses me and I haven't found any tutorials that really clicked.

I know I can echo these vars out, and that will return the contents of load.php into my div.. but that seems clunky, and I doubt that's the way people actually do it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery

```
$("#load_basic").click(function(){
    $.get(loadUrl +  "?language=php&version=5", function(data){
           var obj = eval(data)
           $("#result").html(obj.language + " " + obj.version)      
    });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php $_GET['language'] .= "cool";  $_GET['version']+=2; 
echo "{\"language\" : \"".$_GET['language']."\",\"version\" : \"".$_GET['version']."\"" ?>
```

not tested and not bullet-proof, but the concept is here. Return somthing in your PHP that you can read back (i choose JSON)

Comment: so when I am return variables to my div I need to echo them out in php?

Comment: yes, imagine that your PHP is a webpage for the AJAX function. It reads what's inside. You can return plain HTML, JSON, XML, what you want. You just have to know what format to read in the callback function of the javascript. when you get your data back, read it and append what you want with JQuery. I've slightly edited the code to return JSON above

Comment: Maybe i'm misunderstanding, but that doesn't seem very flexible.  What If I'm echoing out two or three vars in php, and I want them to be seperated and echoed out to different divs..  I wouldn't want to use three different php files to echo out each var.. ?

Comment: that's why I proposed to render JSON... you can render any number of variables while just naming them `{"language" : "JAVA", "version" : "1.6.0b23","compiler" : "hotspot", "user" : "ionfish"}` and when you get `data` back, you evaluate it as a javascript object and use it as an object `var user = obj.usr` etc

Comment: i need to learn about JSON i guess.. don't know anything about it at all.

Comment: JSON is the native Javascript object format. It's very easy to understand. It's very useful when working with JQuery, AJAX, etc. Learning it is not wasting your time ;-)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$.ajax({
  url:YOUR_URL,
  dataType:'json',
  type:'POST',
  data:'&var1=value1&var2=value2',
  beforeSend:function(){
      //
  },
  success:function(response){
      //complete
      $('#container').html(response.result + ' ' + response.other);
  }
});
```

in your php

```
$var1 = $_POST['var1'];
//your proccess
$result = array(
   'result' => 'ok',
   'other' => 'value'
);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: not sure if this ranswers my questions.. you're sending post variables to a php file.  and setting them to other variables.   How am I getting then retrieving these variables?

Comment: if you want to send a form via ajax with jquery you can try with jquery.form.js or maybe in the $.ajax function change:
data:$('#yourformid').serialize()

Answer (score 1):

" What If I'm echoing out two or three vars in php, and I want them to be seperated and echoed out to different divs.. "

I'm ASP and not PHP but I think the prinicple is the same.

I have this is my requesting page:

---

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){  
$("#list").change(onSelectChange);  
});

    function onSelectChange(){  
var selected = $("#list option:selected").val();
var bob = $("#list option:selected").text();

if (selected.length > 0) {
    $.post("twopart.asp", { thing: selected, bob: bob }, function(data) {
        var dataraw= data;
        var dataarray = (dataraw).split("~~~");
        var outone= dataarray["0"];
        var outtwo= dataarray["1"];
        var outthree= dataarray["2"];
        $("#output1").html(outone);
        $("#output2").html(outtwo);
        $("#output3").html(outthree);
    });
}
}
</script>
```

---

and this is in my processing page:

---

```
response.write bunch of stuff and ~~~
response.write bunch of stuff and ~~~
response.write more stuff
```

---

Sorry is the formatting is off- still learning how to do it.

Anyway, the "echoing page" echos its content with the three tildes stuck in there.  Then I parse the return on the tildes and write different places.

Hope this is helpful.

The JSON answer by Grooveek is probably better.